# How to install Neovim on a remote server as a non-sudoer?

Tags: linux

If I am not a sudoer of a remote server, I am wondering whether it is possible for me to install Neovim. Here is the server release:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an overkill if you just wish to install a single programm, but you can use [Junest](https://github.com/fsquillace/junest) to install most command line software without root. It uses an Arch-based Linux distribution inside your home folder.

Another way would be to build Neovim from source and set the `prefix` to a folder you have write access ([Neovim wiki](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#install-from-source)). But this would require your remote server to have all dependencies + CMake installed.